# How to reduce the http request time

Tags: http, networking, browser, request

I am currently located in Hong Kong, it take me around 200ms go to [www.apple.com](http://www.apple.com).

When I ping the site, it return the server IP which located in Hong Kong - 104.89.141.249, I guess the traffic through Hong Kong's data center?

My goal is reduce the request time from 200ms to below 70ms, is there anyway possible way? Is Proxy / VPN a good option? If yes, how can I find the correct location/country to connect faster?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Proxy or VPN could help getting better latency but it may not be enough to the threshold of 70ms.

Latency is affected by many things, the quality of your local connection, your ISP infrastructure, the amount of routers the package has to travel until it reaches destination, and many more.

You could do a trace to the destination IP to check how many routers (hops) are being used to reach destination and the latency of each one. This could be useful to know where is the longest delay and evaluate possible solutions from that.